# Matrix of deviate scores

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to replicate some steps in Jonathon D. Brown's text "Linear Models in Matrix Form: A Hands-On Approach for the Behavioral Sciences" [Brown, 2014, p.12](https://books.google.ca/books?id=POlVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=We%20begin%20by%20calculating%20a%20matrix%20of%20deviate%20scores,%20found%20by%20subtracting%20the%20column%20mean%20from%20each%20corresponding%20column%20entry%20in%20the%20original%20matrix.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyuvyMvoDhAhXF5YMKHecgBpcQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=We%20begin%20by%20calculating%20a%20matrix%20of%20deviate%20scores%2C%20found%20by%20subtracting%20the%20column%20mean%20from%20each%20corresponding%20column%20entry%20in%20the%20original%20matrix.&f=false).  I am creating a "matrix of deviate scores" and I am bothered that I am using the Transpose command twice:

```
X = {{1, 2, 6}, {4, 8, -4}, {5, 6, 5}, {4, 2, 3}}
N[Transpose[Transpose[X] - Mean[X]]]
```

I realize this is artificial; but I am trying to "color within the lines" of the theme of "Matrix Form".  I muddled about with code such as:

```
onesMat = ConstantArray[1, {4, 3}]
xmeans = N[Mean[X]]
Xmeans = Transpose[Transpose[onesMat]*xmeans]
X - Xmeans
```

However, the former code snippet is briefer.  But, still, I seem to be artificially transposing the covariate matrix into a 3 row by 4 column matrix in order to subtract the means and then transposing again to regain the 4 x 3 covariate matrix structure. Is this just what it is?  Or am I abusing Mathematics's syntax for matrices and vectors?

Comment: Does `Standardize[X, Mean, 1 &]` do what you want? This is a pretty common enough operation that they provided this function for the purpose.

Comment: `# - Mean[X] & /@ X // N` or `TranslationTransform[-Mean[X]] /@ X // N`?

Comment: Thank you both.  @J M you have help me understand a feature of the Standardize command that I did not get previously and @kglr you helped remember a syntax I have used before (but neglected) and introduced me to a command (TranslationTransform) that I do not grok at all!

Comment: @J.M. Usually, I would try something like `X - ConstantArray[Mean[X], Length[X]]` but `Standardize` seems to be about 30% faster. That is good to know!

Comment: @BeanSith If you plan that to apply to large datasets, keep in mind to apply `N` _first_ in order to avoid expensive exact precision computations.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thank you. I had not thought to use ConstantArray in this manner.  Moreover, this is more in line with what I am trying to accomplish.  What I am doing is artificial and not targeted at the efficient analysis of data sets.  Rather, I am trying to improve my knowledge of matrix formulations and approaches to data analysis using Mathematica.  For example, if you know the text by Puntanen et al., 2013, "Formulas Useful for Linear Regression Analysis and Related Matrix Theory", I would like to translate their formulae directly into Mathematica - even when it does not make sense.